# is this problem from LinkedIn-API, or my code?

Tags: ios, twitter, linkedin-api

I use [LinkedIn-iPhone API](https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone) to update LinkedIn status, which worked for several times, but most times it does not work well, and it has never worked for the last 5 days. I don't know whether it is the problem of the LinkedIn web site or API connections.

The console log:

> ++ LinkedIn engine reports failure for connection
>   98A66D65-A8EB-4ADF-9B03-76EA54AE5DAE
>   The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (HTTP error 400.), error: Error
>   Domain=HTTP Code=400 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error
>   400.)"

Is the error from the unstable LinkedIn API? or my code?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I found the problem of HTTP error 400, which means: Duplicate updates. I changed the message for updating then it works fine.

Not sure whether moderator should delete this post or not? or how do I close it?

Comment: you just accept you answer for close it ....  Can you tell me how the duplicate update.. because I am facing same error in people/~/shares API ..but I am not sending duplicate update

Comment: @AmitBattan There is also possibility that you redirect url have some capital letter on linkedind setttings and your code has lower letter.Make sure both place has lower letter in iOS and LinkedIN.